# File Group Association while Snapshop Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, filegroups

[image]

I want to know how can I save filegroup structure during snapshop replication in SQL Server? Does this property solve my problem? I want the same filegroups in publishers be created in the subscriber.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information text in the description of the item property provides you with the solution to your question:

<sub>(**emphasis** mine)</sub>

> **Copy file group associations**
> Determines whether to script the associations between file groups and published objects. **The file groups must already exist at the Subscriber**.

If the file groups don't exist at the Subscriber and you set the option **Copy file group associations** to **True**, then the replication will fail, because it will expect the Subscriber to have identical file groups. All transferred objects will be transferred with an additional `...filegroup...` parameter, depending on the object that has to be transferred.

If this option is set to **false** then the objects will be transferred without an additional `...filegroup...` parameter, depending on the object being transferred. The replication will succeed, even if the Subscriber has different file groups, because the objects will be replicated to the default file group.

## Proving It

I created a StackExchange database with the following files and file groups and added a new file group for this question:

```
CREATE DATABASE [StackExchange]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'StackExchange', FILENAME = N'C:\SQL\SQL_DATA\StackExchange.mdf' , SIZE = 56320KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [DEFAULTRO] 
( NAME = N'StackExchange_DefRO', FILENAME = N'C:\SQL\SQL_DATA\StackExchangeRO.ndf' , SIZE = 5120KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [PUBL_SNAP_DBASE]  DEFAULT
( NAME = N'StackExchange_PUBL_SNAP', FILENAME = N'C:\SQL\SQL_DATA\StackExchange_PUBL_SNAP.ndf' , SIZE = 5120KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'StackExchange_log', FILENAME = N'C:\SQL\SQL_LOGS\StackExchange_log.ldf' , SIZE = 112384KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

This database already contains various tables and stored procedures from answering previous questions on DBA.SE. They were created in the `PRIMARY` file group. Here an extract:

#### Input

```
SELECT DS.name AS DataSpaceName 
      ,AU.type_desc AS AllocationDesc 
      ,AU.total_pages / 128 AS TotalSizeMB 
      ,AU.used_pages / 128 AS UsedSizeMB 
      ,AU.data_pages / 128 AS DataSizeMB 
      ,SCH.name AS SchemaName 
      ,OBJ.type_desc AS ObjectType       
      ,OBJ.name AS ObjectName 
      ---,IDX.type_desc AS IndexType 
      ---,IDX.name AS IndexName 
FROM sys.data_spaces AS DS 
     INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units AS AU 
         ON DS.data_space_id = AU.data_space_id 
     INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS PA 
         ON (AU.type IN (1, 3)  
             AND AU.container_id = PA.hobt_id) 
            OR 
            (AU.type = 2 
             AND AU.container_id = PA.partition_id) 
     INNER JOIN sys.objects AS OBJ 
         ON PA.object_id = OBJ.object_id 
     INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS SCH 
         ON OBJ.schema_id = SCH.schema_id 
     ---LEFT JOIN sys.indexes AS IDX 
         ----ON PA.object_id = IDX.object_id 
            ----AND PA.index_id = IDX.index_id
WHERE OBJ.type = 'U' 
AND OBJ.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
AND OBJ.name LIKE 'Q%'
ORDER BY DS.name 
        ,SCH.name 
        ,OBJ.name 
        --,IDX.name
```

#### Output

```
+---------------+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| DataSpaceName | AllocationDesc | TotalSizeMB | UsedSizeMB | DataSizeMB | SchemaName | ObjectType |          ObjectName           |
+---------------+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| DEFAULTRO     | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q196719_Filegroup_2           |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q117478_Encryption_Provider   |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q153379_TestTable             |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q184469_Customer              |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q184469_DVD                   |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q184469_DVD_Purchase          |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q190497_Stats_Hash            |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q196570_Unicode               |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q196719_Filegroup_2           |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q206094_shift                 |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q214251_nvarchar              |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q214251_nvarchar_collation    |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q214251_nvarchar_collation_ws |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Qxxxxx_Join_Question_1        |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Qxxxxx_Join_Question_2        |
+---------------+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
```

### Observations

As you can see all my tables related to questions on DBA.SE have been created in the `PRIMARY` filegroup. (Ok, nearly all of them.)

If I were to create a new table, then it would be created in the `DEFAULT` file group, which is no longer `PRIMARY` but the one named `[PUBL_SNAP_DBASE]`.

### Snapshot Replication

I have created a snapshot replication on my local machine which will replicate any changes from the `StackExchange` database to the `StackExchangeSubscriber` database.

The settings for the **All Tables Properties** - **Copy file group associations** has been set to **`TRUE`**, which should result in an error in the replication.

### The Subscriber Database

```
CREATE DATABASE [StackExchangeSubscriber]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'StackExchangeSubscriber', FILENAME = N'C:\SQL\SQL_DATA\StackExchangeSubscriber.mdf' , SIZE = 56320KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'StackExchangeSubscriber_log', FILENAME = N'C:\SQL\SQL_LOGS\StackExchangeSubscriber_log.ldf' , SIZE = 112384KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

The subscriber database doesn't have the `[DEFAULTRO]` file group, nor does it contain the newly created `[PUBL_SNAP_DBASE]` one.

## Verifying the Replication Status

[image: Snapshot Replication Monitor]

Everything looks good. Let's continue with a modification...

## Modifying the Published Database

Let's go ahead and create a new table in the published database `StackExchange` using DDL. First we'll check the objects in the target/subscriber database with the same script from above.

#### Output

```
+---------------+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| DataSpaceName | AllocationDesc | TotalSizeMB | UsedSizeMB | DataSizeMB | SchemaName | ObjectType |          ObjectName           |
+---------------+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q117478_Encryption_Provider   |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q153379_TestTable             |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q184469_Customer              |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q184469_DVD                   |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q184469_DVD_Purchase          |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q190497_Stats_Hash            |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q196570_Unicode               |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q196719_Filegroup_2           |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q206094_shift                 |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q214251_nvarchar              |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q214251_nvarchar_collation    |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q214251_nvarchar_collation_ws |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Qxxxxx_Join_Question_1        |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Qxxxxx_Join_Question_2        |
+---------------+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
```

Looks the same except for the object that was created in the `[DEFAULTRO]` file group, which wasn't replicated. Hmmm. I think that is a hint of things to come.

### Create Table via DDL

```
USE StackExchange
GO
CREATE TABLE Q221890 (Q221890_ID INT, Q221890_Text VARCHAR(20))
```

I didn't define the file group, so it should be created in the current DEFAULT file group, which is? Exactly.

```
+-----------------+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  DataSpaceName  | AllocationDesc | TotalSizeMB | UsedSizeMB | DataSizeMB | SchemaName | ObjectType | ObjectName |
+-----------------+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| PUBL_SNAP_DBASE | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q221890    |
+-----------------+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

1. I did not define the file group which means the table will be created in the newly defined `[PUBL_SNAP_DBASE]` file group, because it is the new default.
2. The replication will not replicate the new table, because of the **Copy file group associations** setting of **True** in the **All Tables Properties**.

### Insert Data

```
USE [StackExchange]
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Q221890]
           ([Q221890_ID]
           ,[Q221890_Text])
     VALUES
           (1
           ,'Test')
GO
```

### Check Data

```
+------------+--------------+
| Q221890_ID | Q221890_Text |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | Test         |
+------------+--------------+
```

### Checking StackExchangeSubscriber Database in Replication Monitor

[image: Replication Monitor Error]

As can be seen in the monitor error message, the new object is created with the reference to the non-existing file group `[PUBL_SNAP_DBASE]` which causes an error at the subscriber.

### Turn Off the Setting and Retry

We'll turn of the file group setting **Copy file group associations** and re-initialize the snapshot replication. Let's check the list of objects with the script:

```
+---------------+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| DataSpaceName | AllocationDesc | TotalSizeMB | UsedSizeMB | DataSizeMB | SchemaName | ObjectType |          ObjectName           |
+---------------+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q117478_Encryption_Provider   |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q153379_TestTable             |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q184469_Customer              |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q184469_DVD                   |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q184469_DVD_Purchase          |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q190497_Stats_Hash            |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q196570_Unicode               |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q196719_Filegroup_2           |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q206094_shift                 |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q214251_nvarchar              |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q214251_nvarchar_collation    |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q214251_nvarchar_collation_ws |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Q221890                       |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Qxxxxx_Join_Question_1        |
| PRIMARY       | IN_ROW_DATA    |           0 |          0 |          0 | dbo        | USER_TABLE | Qxxxxx_Join_Question_2        |
+---------------+----------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
```

Yes, the new table in the file group has been replicated.

---

## Answering Your Question

> I want to know how can I save filegroup structure during snapshot replication in SQL Server?

You can't. (See answer further down)

> Does this property solve my problem?

No, which was proved with the above procedure

> I want the same filegroups in publishers be created in the subscriber.

You will have to create the file groups at the target/subscriber before you create the objects in those file groups.

**Turning on the option will cause errors, if the file groups do not exist.**